# Update table in Word Add-in

Tags: binding, office-js, word-addins

I'm developing a Word Add-in using office.js. I would like to programmatically add a table to the document and later update the table with fresh data.

I'm creating the table using `setSelectedDataAsync(CoercionType.Table)` and then I'm using `addFromSelectionAsync(BindingType.Table)` to set binding. When I call `setDataAsync()` the underlying table's structure shouldn't be modified, so the update is performed only if data has the same number of columns. If data has less columns, the extra columns are left unchanged (risky!). If data has more columns an error is raised, saying that "The supplied data object does not match the size of the current selection".

Which is the best solution to draw and update the table with different schema (rows/columns) at each update?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the new [Table](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/WordJs_1.3_Openspec/word/resources/table.md) functionalities as part of the Word Api 1.3 update for Office.js.

You can find instructions about the [preview of those new APIs here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/WordJs_1.3_Openspec).

Comment: Philip, thank you but I can't mark your answer as accepted, since Word API 1.3 is still in beta and supported only by the latest Office 365, unfortunately... I should keep finding a way with the obsolete office.js shared api, which is more widely supported.